# Wilcoxon rank sum test critical values?

Tags: probability, statistics

A am a bit confused, when we are using choosing the critical value for a wilcoxon rank sum test (2-samples unpaired) when do we use the upper bound and when do we use the lower bound. So far i have only used the lower bound with the lowest of the two W values but keep seeing questions (A-level exam questions) where they specifically take the upper bound. For what reasons and when do we use the upper critical value and when the lower??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$, $n$ be the smaller and larger sample size respectively.  The upper and lower critical bound for the rank sum statistic are typically defined as critical values for the smaller sample size.  As you point out, if given the lower critical value, $c$, then the upper critical value can be found to be $2(0.5mn+0.5m(m+1))-c$.  In picking the critical bounds, one has to be careful to match them to the alternative, one-sided vs two-sided, as well as the direction of the alternative if it's one sided.

Take for example m=4 and n=7.  If your alternative is two-sided and significance level is .05 ($\alpha=.05$), then the critical values would be 13 and 35.  You would reject the null hypothesis if $W_1 \le 13$ or $W_1\ge 35$.  Notice that each of these critical values correspond to critical values for one tailed tests with $\alpha=.025$.

Now, suppose your alternative is that the group with the smaller sample size tends to have smaller values than the other group, then you would use the lower critical value of 14 for $\alpha=.05$.  If your one-sided alternative is that the group with the smaller sample size tends to have larger values than the other group, then you would use the upper critical value of 34 for $\alpha=.05$.

Comment: I may be wrong but i thought we find the upper critical value by 2(0.5mn+0.5m(m+1))-c where m is the smaller sample size??

Comment: @Joseph sorry, it appears I misunderstood your question, will edit my post shortly

Comment: so for a two tailed test if we have W1 from the smaller sample and W2 from the larger, if W1<W2 we use the lower bound and if W1>W2 we use the upper bound whilst always using W1 as our test statistic is this correct?? thanks

Comment: Yes, $W_1$ is always your test statistic.  Which bound you compare it to depends on the research question of interest, not whether $W_1<W_2$ or $W_1>W_2$.  Do you know how to decide if it's a one or two sided alternative hypothesis?

Comment: Yes just not when to use the upper or lower bound in a 2 tailed test

Comment: In the two tailed test, you would compare $W_1$ to each of the critical values. Let $c_1$ be the lower bound and let $c_2$ be the upper bound. Then you would reject the null hypothesis if $W_1 \leq c_1$ or $W_1\ge c_2$.